How can I set up the inputs to this scatter_chart?
My data looks like this:



Name
Date
10%
20%
30%
...
100%




Anne
1/1/24
3
5
1
...
92


Anne
1/2/24
4
8
2
...
78


Anne
1/3/24
7
9
6
...
47



What I would like is to create a Snowflake Streamlit scatterplot with the following information:

there will only be one name (Anne in this case) which will be the title of the chart
the percentages will be my x axis
the values at each percentage will be my y axis
the dates will be separated by color

I have the following code:
import streamlit as st
df = [...same as table...]
st.scatter_chart(df,
                 x = "DATE",
                 y = ["10%", "20%", "30%", ..., "100%", 
                 color = "DATE")

While the result of running the code outputs no errors, all I see is the "DATE" at the bottom of the chart and everything else is empty. I don't think my inputs are correct, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

It looks like I needed to import the altair library as the standard streamlit scatter chart functionality was too simple. I needed to create a melted dataframe and use an altair chart to display the data
Here's what I did:
import altair as alt

chart_df = newdf.drop(columns = ['NAME'])
chart_df = chart_df.astype({col: 'float' for col in chart_df.columns if col != 'DATE'})

numeric_cols = sorted(chart_df.columns[1:].to_list(), key=float)

chart_df = chart_df[['DATE'] + numeric_cols]

chart_df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(chart_df['DATE'], format='%Y.%m.%d')
chart_df = chart_df.melt(id_vars = ['DATE'], var_name = '%age', value_name = 'Output')

chart_df['DATE'] = chart_df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#st.write('Melted Dataframe:', chart_df)
chart = alt.Chart(chart_df).mark_circle(size = 60).encode(alt.X('%age:O', 
                                                                sort = numeric_cols),
                                                          alt.Y('Output:Q'),
                                                          color='DATE:N',
                                                          tooltip=['DATE:N', '%age:O', 'Output:Q']
                                                         ).properties(width = 600, height = 400)
st.altair_chart(chart, use_container_width = True)

Let me know if you have any questions about this. It still isn't perfect but gets the job done.
